# How to export users from oracle database. (Oracle 10g express edition)

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, export

I am trying to export the user from database, but its showing

[image]

But if i am trying to export entire database then its successfully completing.
I want to export only one user.
How to fix the problem with this Oracle character set.

Thanking you!

Comment: so... enter the user/schema you want to export?

Comment: if you want to export only one user, why not just "copy & paste" the user-info from one DB to another ? also, any DB tool (like toad, sqldeveloper etc) can help you export your data to excel/csv/other formats

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To export just 1 user you can type the following:

```
exp system/<system_password>@<database> file=<user>.dmp owner=<user>
```

The export utility will ask no further questions.

Comment: Thank you! 
But what is the character set problem in which i used earlier.
That is success in the case of entire database, but not in users.

Comment: I don't know what character set problem you are talking about. There is nothing that points to a character set problem in de screen output you posted.

Comment: Just as a comment. The tool for exporting can be found in the bin/ folder.
For exmaple.
C:\apps\oracleXE\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin

Answer (score 2):

The previous one didn't work for me but the below worked for me. Kindly check

```
exp system/<system_password> file=<export_filename>.dmp owner=<schema_user_name>
```

**Example**

```
exp system/oracle file=test_database.dmp owner=test_database
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

```
          ---create user
```

CREATE USER john IDENTIFIED BY Oracle1234;

```
          ---grant sesssion
```

GRANT CREATE SESSION TO john;

```
          ---grant read and write
```

grant read , write on directory datapump to john;
-----check coonection

connect john/Oracle1234@TEPDB

```
         ---grant full export permission
```

SQL>  grant EXP_FULL_DATABASE to john;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> alter user john quota unlimited on system;

User altered.

SQL> exit

**bash-4.4$** ***expdp john/Oracle1234@TEP schemas=john directory=datapump dumpfile=people.dmp logfile=impeople.log;***